# HSQL DB Conflicts with JBoss

Tags: jboss, hsqldb

I would like to use a custom version of the HSQL DB in an application that I am deploying in JBoss.  However, JBoss already contains an HSQLDB.jar.  The JBoss jar is being resolved by my application instead of the custom jar in my ear.

How can I use a different version of HSQL in my web application from the one that JBoss uses internally?

Can I remove the HSQLDB.jar included with JBoss without negatively impacting the Application Server?

Answer (score 0):

The custom version it's just a newer version? If it's that the case than you can simply replace the jar in the Jboss lib folder. Jboss uses HSQLDB as far as I know for queue persistence.